# how to play sound on Destroy()

Tags: unity-game-engine

Warning - new to Unity3d (about 4 hours of work in) but experienced with programming.  Also can get long winded...

So I'm kinda following a basic "Pick up the coins" game tutorial.  Immediately embettering it, I've figured out how to make the coins rotate/spin, get picked up, etc.

I can play sound - on wake-up/create, or uncheck the box and call

`GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();`

Inside of my `onTriggerEnter()` and I can get sound.

Unfortunately, when the next line calls `Destroy(gameObject)` ... the sound doesn't play.  I can comment out the destroy call and everything else works including playing the pickup sound, but I do kinda need to remove coins from the scene when they've been "grabbed".

I could move the AudioSource to another object that won't get destroyed, or even create a MyGame c# script that controls all sounds, coin count, time, etc.

But it also seems to me that I should be able to make a "coin" asset, and any project I import it to it should Just Work with its own AS, the mp3 with it, etc and so forth.

So... How to create a stand alone object that when it is collided with plays a sound and then `Destroy()`s itself?

My complete `Coin.cs` file - it is attached to a `Coin` made by resizing a Column 3D type object. AudioSource attached to coin, will play fine If the call to `Destroy()` is commented out. Running latest Beta of Unity3d for Linux (sorry, no Mac or Win machines and it sucks in virtualbox).  Not sure how to post project info, etc. but if needed tell me ...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Coin : MonoBehaviour {

    public float rotate_speed=200f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider Col){
        if(Col.CompareTag("Player")){
            Player.gotCoin();
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    void Update () {
        // make coin tumble
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.left, rotate_speed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.back, rotate_speed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, rotate_speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you REALLY wanted to self-contain the audio with the object, you could try something like:

```
public class Coin : MonoBehaviour
{
    // A generic Collider... You can be more specific if you want.
    public Collider collider;

    // Reference your renderer here.
    public MeshRenderer renderer;

    // Reference you AudioSource here.
    public AudioSource audioSource;

    public float rotate_speed = 200f;

    private bool isActive = true;

    void OnTriggerEnter ( Collider Col )
    {
        if ( Col.CompareTag ( "Player" ) )
        {
            Player.gotCoin ( );
            audioSource.Play ( );
            isActive = false;
            collider.enabled = renderer.enabled = false;
        }
    }


    void Update ( )
    {
        if ( isActive )
        {
            // make coin tumble
            transform.Rotate ( Vector3.left, rotate_speed * Time.deltaTime );
            transform.Rotate ( Vector3.back, rotate_speed * Time.deltaTime );
            transform.Rotate ( Vector3.up, rotate_speed * Time.deltaTime );
        }
        else
        {
            // If the coin is "dead", we check to see if the audio is still playing.
            // If not, we destroy the object.
            if ( !audioSource.isPlaying )
                Destroy ( gameObject );
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, the code should turn off the collider, so you don't retrigger picking up the same coin, and turn off the renderer, so it's not displayed on screen. As far as the game player is concerned, it's not there anymore.

Though.. I'd still just use an audio manager, and use a pool of "coins" (instead of destroying), as "coins" are generally many in number. But that's another story for another day.

Comment: Indeed it is.  If this were pure Java, I'd have a game class that had a player instance and an array of coin instances and ...  Thanks much for the quick answer!

Comment: And why do you think you can't? You'd be surprised how well "pure" coding can be used in Unity. Using centralised managers means that you're not calling the Unity event methods, such as `Update()`, on every GameObject. That can amount to quite a lot of method calls. When implemented in a Manager, it's called once, on the manager's `Update()` method.

Comment: @ivanivan For example, see that `rotate_speed * Time.deltaTime`? You could calculate that once, in a Coin Manager, and then apply that value to all the coin instances, instead of calculating it 3 times for each and every coin GameObject. That's just one instant optimisation.